# Spider of the American continent spotted Europe. Is it expected?

Tags: species-distribution, invasive-species

While hiking in a nature reserve in Bulgaria I saw a big yellow and black spider. I took some pictures and when I went back home I did some searches and identified it as an [Argiope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argiope_aurantia), common name is Yellow and Black garden spider.

The description matches, the body was almost as big as the upper phalanx of a thumb. But the Wikipedia page states that it is native of the American continent. Is it an invasive species? Is it common to find it in Europe?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Argiope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argiope_(spider))* is a cosmopolitan genus (the link is for the genus, not the individual species you linked).

*Argiope* species *[A. bruennchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argiope_bruennichi)*, and *[A. lobata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argiope_lobata)* are found in Europe in particular. Based on your photos I think this is likely to be *A. bruennchi* rather than *A. lobata*, as it has strong yellow and black bands and lacks the lobed edge of the abdomen of *A. lobata*.

Comment: Yes, may be an A. bruennichi. One small doubt is that the body size was about the double of the average size of the female.